# Show attribute value 0 if its coming null (PHP)(XML)

Tags: php, arrays, xml

```
 $xml_data = simplexml_load_file('demo.xml');
 foreach ($xml_data->Game as $game) {
 $t = $game['Time'];
 $odds = $game->xpath('SportsBook[@Name="5Dimes"]/Odds');
 if(isset($odds)){
 $valueLT=$odds[0]->attributes()->LineType;
 echo 'Time: ' . $t . ' LineType: '.$valueLT
 . '<br/>' . PHP_EOL;
 }
 }
```

demo.xml

```
 <GameOdds SportsCode="MLB">
 <Game Code="121" Date="07/06/2017" Time="1:45 PM">
 <SportsBook ID="5" Name="5Dimes">
 <Odds LineType="2"  LastUpdated="10"  />
 </SportsBook>
 <SportsBook ID="5" Name="3Dimes">
 <Odds LineType="3"  LastUpdated="20"  />
 </SportsBook> </Game>
 <Game Code="121" Date="07/06/2017" Time="1:45 PM">
 <SportsBook ID="5"  Name="5Dimes" />
 <SportsBook ID="5" Name="3Dimes">
 <Odds LineType="3"  LastUpdated="20"  />
 </SportsBook> </Game>
 <Game Code="122" Date="07/02/2017" Time="1:46 PM">
 <SportsBook ID="2" Name="5Dimes">
 <Odds LineType="4"  LastUpdated="10"  />
 </SportsBook>
 <SportsBook ID="6" Name="3Dimes">
 <Odds LineType="36"  LastUpdated="30"  />
 </SportsBook> 
 </Game></GameOdds>
```

Right now i am getting Fatal error as i dont have Odds data in 2nd game. If i dont have any 5Dimes odds in any Sportsbook. i just want to show value null there.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on null

**Result**

```
Time: 1:45 PM LineType:2
Time: 1:45 PM LineType:0
Time: 1:46 PM LineType:4
```

Thanks

Comment: So check `$odds` values. I suppose `$odds` are always __set__, so `isset` is true. Use `empty` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
foreach ($xml_data->Game as $game) {
    $t = $game['Time'];
    $odds = $game->xpath('SportsBook[@Name="5Dimes"]/Odds');
    //var_dump($odds); - you will see 
    // it's empty array if there's no `Odds` tags

    // Some default value
    $valueLT = 'NULL';

    // add a strict check if exactly `$odds[0]` exists in `$odds`
    if(!empty($odds[0])) {
        // get value from attribute
        $valueLT = $odds[0]->attributes()->LineType;
    }

    echo 'Time: ' . $t . ' LineType: '.$valueLT . '<br/>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
Time: 1:45 PM LineType: 2<br/>
Time: 1:45 PM LineType: NULL<br/>
Time: 1:46 PM LineType: 4<br/>
```